# A simple enough riddle

Tags: riddle

Here's a simple riddle.

> I can be found in the ocean as well as in your pocket.
>
> I can be found in the adventurous as well as the curious.
>
> I can be found new when cast from old.

Answer (score 5):

It is

> The letter **O**
>
>  The letter **O** appears in the words *ocean*, *pocket*, *adventurous*, and *curious*.  If you cast it from the word *old*, you will find it "new" (in a new word by itself).

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Gold
>
>  As in the sea are goldfish.
>
>  Gold coins in your pocket.
>
>  Gold could be a reward for the adventurous.
>
>  Golden antiques could interest the curious.
>
>  And when you melt it down you get a new bar of gold from old gold objects

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong.. But I don't think there are goldfish in the sea

Comment: Taking in consideration of the riddle everything else fits but yes you are right @Xylius